# R - string manipulation and extraction

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a string `strEx <- "list(A, B, C, D)"` that I would like to store as a character vector:

```
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

I'm not very good at regex (might be overkill as well, but I will need more of it in the future) which is probably part of my problem. I have a solution that I feel is too much code/bad form.

It gives me what I want in the end but I still need to split it on commas and flatten it. I just feel this is a too crude a way to go about it. Anyone have a prettier solution?

```
d <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", strEx)
d1 <- unlist(tstrsplit(d, ", ", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: So, in the real case, you have some literal text around the comma-delimited values?

Comment: Try `res <- str_match_all(strEx, "(?:list\\(\\s*|(?!^)\\G,?\\s*)([^,)]+)")` with `library(stringr)`. However, your approach is very good already.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In the real case it might be text(A, B, C, D, ..., k)text. Always only one block of (), the closing ) might be the last character in the string, or might not be.

Comment: The real question is why you have such a string. That's what you should work on avoiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the expression like this:

```
#parse the expression
pEx <- parse(text = strEx)[[1]]
```

Expressions are actually lists of symbols and can be treated as such. Here we turn everything except `list` into characters:

```
vapply(pEx[-1], as.character, FUN.VALUE = "")
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

However, if you need to parse a string (which is what you propose as a solution using regex too), some preceding step should usually be improved. You should not have an expression that needs to be parsed.

See this:

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(106)
#If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#   -- Thomas Lumley
#      R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: Thx Roland, I'll accept this as an answer and you raise a good point. This was mostly a trial to get to know string manipulation a little bit better but I did change this part last night which removed most of the string manipulation if not all. 

I have a 1GB csv before me with manually inserted data that I need to clean. I agree that it would have been better if it had been done right from the start but it's the result of years of insertion done by hundreds of different people, so what's done is done :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `eval(parse(...))`, adding quotes to every letters :

```
unlist(eval(parse(text=gsub("([A-Z])", "\"\\1\"", "list(A, B, C, D)"))))
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

If you haven't commas in the first string, you can add commas and remove the last one with another `sub` step:

```
unlist(eval(parse(text=sub(",(?=[)])", "", gsub("([A-Z])", "\"\\1\",", "list(A B C D)"), perl=TRUE))))
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Comment: thx but unfortunently it doesn't seem to work for me when I supply it as a string like this z <- "list(A, B, C, D)" and it needs to work programmatically. Your answer works as it is though.

Comment: @ErrantBard I'm sorry I unvoluntarily added commas. I edited with an option when you don't have commas in your string. Hope it works better for you

Comment: @ErrantBard cool :-) sorry for the "comma-adding" in the first place

Comment: @Roland I know we should always avoid `eval(parse(..))`. Your solution is perfect, definitely the best way to handle `strEx`. Why don't you post it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your 2-step approach is very good and readable. If you want to try and grab items inside a block of text *in one go*, you can use a PCRE regex with `\G` and `\K` operators using the base R functions:

```
> g <- unlist(regmatches(strEx, gregexpr("(?:list\\(\\s*|(?!^)\\G(?:,\\s*)?)\\K[^,)]+", strEx, perl=TRUE)))
> g
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:list\\(\\s*|(?!^)\\G(?:,\\s*)?)` - the `list(` and 0+ whitespaces substring (see `list\\(\\s*` part) or the end of the previous successful match (see `(?!^)\\G`) and an optional sequence of `,` and zero or more whitespaces  (see `(?:,\\s*)?`)
- `\\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `[^,)]+` - 1 or more chars other than `,` and `)`.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/dToImW/1).

Comment: +1 for that Wiktor, both for the evaluation of my attempt and an alternative version complete with pattern details, the last part with the details helped alot. I'll  give some time for others to attempt an answer otherwise I will happily accept yours

Comment: Also, this is a solution using only base R functions.